# Find the general solution for $t^2y'' -2y = t^2 -1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question already gives $y_1=t^2$ and $y_2=t^{-1}$ as solutions to the homogeneous equation.

So the homogeneous equation is:

$y_h = c_1t^2 + c_2t^{-1}$

So we need to find the particular solution, we have a polynomial as the RHS of the EDO, so our $y_p$ will be

$y_p = At^2 + Bt + C$

$\Rightarrow y_p'= 2At + B$

$\Rightarrow y_p''= 2A$

We substitute our findings in the EDO:

$t^2(2A) - 2(At^2+Bt+C) = t^2 - 1$

$-2Bt - 2C = t^2 - 1$

$\Rightarrow -2B = 0, -2C = -1$

$\Rightarrow B = 0, C = 1/2, A = ???$

The part of the LHS that was multiplying A cancelled itself, so we can't determine A. What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Here I propose an alternative way to solve it for the sake of curiosity.

We can rearrange the LHS in order to obtain:

\begin{align*}
t^{2}y'' - 2y = t^{2} - 1 & \Longleftrightarrow (t^{2}y'' + 2ty') - (2ty' + 2y) = t^{2} - 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (t^{2}y')' - 2(ty)' = t^{2} - 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow t^{2}y' - 2ty = \frac{t^{3}}{3} - t + c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' - \frac{2y}{t} = \frac{t}{3} - \frac{1}{t} + \frac{c}{t^{2}}
\end{align*}

where you can apply the integrating factor method.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So it cannot be solved by the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: What I proposed is an alternative approach. I will edit my answer to include it.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$c_1 t^2+\frac{c_2}{t}+\frac{1}{18} \left(-2 t^2+6 t^2 \log (t)+9\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

When the forcing function $t^2-1$  matches one of the homogeneous solutions, you have to toss in a factor of $\ln t$.  Try instead

$$y_p = At^2\ln t + Bt \ln t + C\ln t.$$

(This is the equivalent of the constant coefficient case when you multiply by $t$ when the forcing function matches a homogeneous solution.)

Comment: $t^2$ matches, but $-1$ doesn't.  So in addition to what you wrote, we need just $+ D$.

Comment: Amazing, I tried to do this with a factor of $t$, which didn't work. Why ln $t$ though? I could really use some reference in this.

Comment: In the constant coefficient case, the $t$ comes from a version of variation of parameters.  One way to do the Euler equation is to substitute $t = e^x$ and solve the new equation.  The extra $x$ here is equivalent to the extra $\ln t$.  Most intro DE books should have this.

Answer (score 1):

$$t^2y'' -2y = t^2 $$
$$\implies y_p=At^2\ln t$$
And for the second DE:
$$t^2y'' -2y =  -1$$
you need $y_p=B$.

So that for the original DE:
$$t^2y'' -2y = t^2 -1$$
$$\implies y_p=At^2 \ln t+ B$$